# Tensorflow, get static shapes of tensors

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am trying to use the [Unet model](https://github.com/qubvel/segmentation_models) output in other neural network, the problem is, I need to get the real shape without None instead of dimensions, could you please tell me how I can do it? unet_model.summary() shows the real shape, but when I try to get the output tensor, its shape is None

```
unet_model =  Unet(input_shape=(256,256,3),backbone_name='resnet50',encoder_weights='imagenet', decoder_block_type='transpose')
f_i = Input(shape=(256,256,3))
```

```
unet_model.call(f_i)
```

```
unet_model.layers[-1].output
```

[link to the screenshot with the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQeLq.png)

```
# unet_model.summary()
....
sigmoid (Activation)            (None, 256, 256, 1)  0           final_conv[0][0]    

# unet_model.call(f_i)
<tf.Tensor 'sigmoid_5/Sigmoid:0' shape=(?, ?, ?, 1) dtype=float32>

# unet_model.layers[-1].output   
<tf.Tensor 'sigmoid_5/Sigmoid:0' shape=(?, ?, ?, 1) dtype=float32>
```

I expect to receive a tensor with the shape = (None, 256, 256, 1)

I use tensorflow==1.14.0, keras==2.3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the layer shape of the model using below lines.

```
for layer in unet_model.layers:
    print(layer.output_shape)
```

Comment: thanks, for some reason, ```unet_model.layers[-1].output.shape``` and ```unet_model.layers[-1].output_shape``` give different results, your answer solved my problem, thanks